# Hdri map flickers in Layout workspace, but works normally in the other workspaces

Tags: 3d-view, hdri, world, workspaces

[image]
[image]
[image]

Maybe someone knows, what the problem is?

Comment: I suspect without any further explanation, nobody knows what the problem is. You post 3 screenshots but explain absolutely nothing. You say in the title, the HDRI is flickering. In which way? You show three still images, flickering is usually visible in animation. I cannot see any flicker in those stills. And why is the _Fake User_ option on the world shader keyframe animated? Never seen someone do that, did not know it is possible and do not know what is the use of that... Maybe this has to do with whatever flickering you experience?

Comment: Flickering when i move viewport position by using middle mouse button, and it doesn’t show up at all, even when I don’t move it. I see just one of the hdri map colors, which changes, when I move scene position with middle mouse button.

Comment: Now this was a useful information which could have been needed in the question. This kind of flickering is normal. You can only see the HDRI map when in perspective view (at least with equirectangular projection). In orthographic view you only get a color, which is constantly changing when moving the view because it is averaged over everything visible in the current view or just the color in the center of the current view (I actually never bothered to find out what exactly it is showing). Unfortunately you did not tag me so I was not notified of your comment. Well, you found out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, you need switch from *Orthographic* to *Perspective*.

Comment: I don’t consider this a solution. The problem is that orthographic view is useful — I use it a lot — and having an HDRI background causes flashing in orthographic view! Any thoughts? (Or should I open a new Q?)